# Compile and Install Gedit from Source on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, gedit, source-code

It is pretty obvious what I need to do, but below are the details just in case.

I want to install and configure Gedit's latest version into my Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty tahr along with installing it's dependencies first, in such a way that my system uses that Gedit as default Text file editor.

I downloaded gedit-3.20.1.tar.xz from ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/.

I tried `./configure` and stuff with gedit-3.20.1.tar.xz source but when I run `make` and `make install` commands, it displays below error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `./configure` output for error messages, too?

Comment: Yes but I don't get how to install the dependencies and I don't find their latest versions in apt-cache search, so I want anyone to list out all commands to install dependencies first and then Gedit latest ver.